# Specify fields returned by Google Places API call

Tags: google-places-api

Google places response contains a lot of data. Most of which I don't need. Is there a way to specify which fields I want to receive?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can now specify which fields you want returned using the `fields` parameter

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Example of returning specific fields from Google Headquarters (from link above):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&fields=name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: Keep in mind that some fields may not be available to certain types of places. E.g. a place of type "premise" or "subpremise" won't have a phone number associated with it, even if you ask for it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603774/google-maps-place-details-api-not-returning-phone-numbers

Answer (score 3):

From the **[documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)**, **No** there isn't any parameter in Google Places API that you can define only the fields you need in the response. You can't somehow reduce the data in the response. They come as it is.

The only parameter that can change the size of the response is `extensions=review_summary` which brings some **more** fields and not less as you require. I am just mentioning it in case you included it in your call

Comment: It is suprising that Google provides no way to reduce the request size.

Comment: @user3002996 As long as the response is quick a little bit bigger JSON doesn't create problems in processing

Comment: Since 2017, the ```review_summary``` is deprecated.