# Google Maps Place Details API Not Returning Phone Numbers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I'm making a call to Place Details. I want to get the phone number(formatted_phone_number) back.  That field isn't being returned and I don't see any phone numbers in the response.  I set the fields property to `null` to get all of the available properties

```
const placeDetails = (result) => {
    console.log('placeDetails');

    const request = {
        placeId: result.place_id,
        fields: null //['name', 'formatted_phone_number', 'rating', 'reviews', 'website']
    };

    service.getDetails(request, placeDetailsCb);
}

const placeDetailsCb = (place, status) => {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log('place', place)
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Place Details Response not OK. Status: ${status}`)
    }
}
```

response

> Object { address_components: (9) […], adr_address: "563 2nd St, San Francisco, CA 94107-1411, USA", formatted_address: "563 2nd St,
>   San Francisco, CA 94107, USA", geometry: {…}, icon:
>   "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
>   id: "69cfece0624106a3c1dc8669ffa975fb6464faeb", name: "563 2nd St",
>   place_id: "ChIJrfXAU3iAhYARyUGceTIdcMg", reference:
>   "ChIJrfXAU3iAhYARyUGceTIdcMg", scope: "GOOGLE", … } api.js:57:17

I also tried both the Nearby Places search and Autocomplete search.  The Autocomplete filtering by type=establishment didn't return any results and leaving off that filter only returned premise and geocode types, not establishement.

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=563 2nd St, San Francisco, CA 94107, USA&type=establishment&key=<APIKEY>
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=563 2nd St, San Francisco, CA 94107, USA&key=<APIKEY>
```

The Nearby Search did return establishments, but not the one that comes up in maps.google.com ([establishment](https://www.google.com/maps/place/21st+Amendment+Brewery+%26+Restaurant/@37.7825321,-122.3946465,17z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x8085807853c0f5ad:0xc8701d32799c41c9!2s563+2nd+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94107!3b1!8m2!3d37.7825279!4d-122.3924578!3m4!1s0x80857de927010363:0xa48cec2d7700abeb!8m2!3d37.7825242!4d-122.3924674))

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.7825321,-122.3946465&radius=10&type=establishment&key=<APIKEY>
```

Comment: What place are you trying to get the phone number from? Your example response shows `place_id: ChIJrfXAU3iAhYARyUGceTIdcMg` which type is `premise`. From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types): `premise` indicates a named location, usually a building or collection of buildings with a common name.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I searched for the addresses of 3 different businesses which have phone numbers listed on Google Maps.  At least one of these businesses should only have one business at the address.  None of them had the phone numbers come back in the response.  Am I supposed to do another search once I have the premise?  If so, what place_id would I pass to it.

Comment: I have no idea how you obtained this place id. All I can say is that it doesn't correspond to a specific business. You need to provide more information and examples of how you get these place ids. If a business has a listed phone number in Google Maps, you should find it in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Latest update is that phone number is a part of a "contact" search on Google Maps API, which costs more. So, it is kept separate from the results. You will not get the phone number with the places ID search.

Reference:- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details

Answer (score 0):

Place ID `ChIJrfXAU3iAhYARyUGceTIdcMg` is of `premise` type. Its address is `563 2nd St, San Francisco, CA 94107, USA` which has no public phone number in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/563+2nd+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94107,+USA/@37.7825279,-122.3946465,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8085807853c0f5ad:0xc8701d32799c41c9!8m2!3d37.7825279!4d-122.3924578) either. Hence the Places API cannot possibly return a phone number because there just isn't one. **This is a house.**

In order to get `formatted_phone_number`, you need to search for places of `establishment` (business) type. So if instead of the above premise, you search for the restaurant next to it, i.e. `21st Amendment Brewery & Restaurant` (place ID `ChIJYwMBJ-l9hYAR66sAdy3sjKQ`), you **will** get a phone number, the same one shown in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/21st+Amendment+Brewery+%26+Restaurant/@37.7825242,-122.3930146,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80857de927010363:0xa48cec2d7700abeb!8m2!3d37.7825242!4d-122.3924674).

Take a look at this jsfiddle for Places Details demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/v8mfzy4r/

As a side-node, place IDs can be retrieved from the Place Autocomplete and Place Search services and you can restrict results to a specific type such as `establishment` (for Autocomplete) or any of its subtypes, e.g. `restaurant` (for Place Search).

This is all explained in detail in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) which I recommend you take some time to go through, especially because this is a [billable](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing) library and Contact Data SKU fields have an additional cost.

Hope this helps!

Comment: that's helpful.  I did try both the Autocomplete and Nearby Search services and wasn't able to get the business results.  I edited my question to show the additional calls.  It doesn't look like you can filter Place Search by types, only specify whether to get back the types in the response.

Comment: You can restrict Autocomplete prediction results to a supported type as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types). I see 2 issues in your request in edit though; first it's `types` not `type`, secondly, you're still trying to query a `premise` hence the API returns ZERO_RESULTS when you add `establishment` type but returns results if you don't.

Comment: Please try Google's example, select "Establishments" option; the locations that show up are all business places you can get phone numbers from (if available). Any place of other types won't show up when you type it (such as that premise address you keep trying to query), but will if you select other options (i.e. "All", "Geocodes" etc.): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: As for your Nearby Search, note that you're searching for businesses within 10 meters of `37.7825321,-122.3946465` which is 160 meters away according to Google Maps... Try narrowing down your search a bit, e.g. see: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.782476,-122.392390&radius=20&type=establishment&key=KEY

Comment: I still don't see how by only having the address I can get the right place_id for the establishment.  In your example in the answer you searched for the business name and that gave you the right place_id, but I only have the address.  As far as the Nearby Search goes, when I searched for the address and the establishment in maps.google.com, 37.7825321,-122.3946465 were the coordinates that came back, but when I put the coordinates in directly, it pointed to a location about 2 blocks away.  I changed the radius to 500 and it still doesn't bring it up.

Comment: By address do you mean the one of the house? ("563 2nd St, San Francisco, CA 94107, USA") Maybe I'm not being clear enough. This is a house. You can't get its phone number with Autocomplete or with any other Google Maps service. But if you do have its coordinates you can get the place IDs (and the phone numbers with Places Details service) of establishments that are nearby using Nearby Search, which I assume is your actual use case.

Comment: The reason you cannot find that restaurant in your Nearby Search is because your query is too broad. Note that the API returns up to 20 places per query (60 at most) sorted by importance, and `establishment` type means all kinds of businesses not just restaurants. And you're querying a 500 meters radius... You really must narrow down the search.

Comment: If you want to use `37.7825321,-122.3946465` then use a subtype of `establishment` (e.g. `restaurant`) or add more parameters (e.g. `keyword` or `name`) or use `rankby=distance` instead of radius. E.g. this query finds that restaurant just fine: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.7825321,-122.3946465&rankby=distance&type=restaurant&key=KEY

Comment: I do see that your last query returns multiple restaurants, including '21st Amendment Brewery & Restaurant'.  However, I'm trying to make the search work without having to know ahead of time that it's a restaurant. Let me walk through the exact manual scenario I'm trying to replicate programmatically.  If you type in '563 2nd St, San Francisco, CA 94107' into maps.google.com, you'll get back the premise, but if you scroll down, under 'At this location' you'll see the restaurant.  Just that restaurant, no other businesses and I didn't have to specify that I was looking for a restaurant...

Comment: So it seems that Google stores these separately but it has the association somehow.  If I click on that restaurant, then you'll see that its address is the same as the address I searched for '563 2nd St, San Francisco, CA 94107'.  This also matches what's on their website.  Also, for some reason the coordinates in the search by that address and the search by that business name don't match even though they are both at the same location.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I believe I fully understand your use case now. The "At this location" feature is not present in the Maps APIs (only in Google Maps). However, note that coordinates change depending on the map's center and zoom level, so in order to get that address' exact coordinate you should geocode it first, e.g. using [this tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D563%25202nd%2520St%252C%2520San%2520Francisco%252C%2520CA%252094107%252C%2520USA) you'll get `37.782528,-122.392458`. This is the location's coordinate, regardless of zoom level.

Comment: Now use this lat/lng in your Nearby Search request and you'll get back the restaurant `21st Amendment Brewery & Restaurant` within a reasonable radius, e.g. 20 or 50 or 100, see: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.782528,-122.392458&radius=100&type=establishment&key=KEY

Comment: Let me know if this helps and is what answers your original question and i'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually I'm sorry, `establishment` is not in the list of [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) for places searches, it's only supported in Autocomplete. So the nearby search query should be: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.782528,-122.392458&radius=100&key=KEY

Answer (score -1):

Use the fields parameter to specify a comma-separated list of place data types to return.

Fields correspond to Place Details results

Probably the place id you entered is incorrect .

Comment: the place id is correct.  It's returning data as you can see. The problem is that the phone number fields are not coming through.  If fields is not specified, all fields are returned, as described in the documentation.